# Git, can't commit to remote webserver repository

Tags: git, ssh

I have a webserver rented and local development environment set up. My aim is to get the job process working like this - I do some local changes, commit them to the rented webserver test environment and if everything works to live environment.

My webserver provider has SSH support and I have set up the RSA keys. I copied all the files (including .git folder) from the local environment to live via FTP.

The problem is I can't seem to be able to commit. I tried enabling chmod to 777, but I still get this error:

```
C:\wamp\www\site17>git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/yod/.ssh/id_rsa':
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know I have the correct psw, path and that the repository exists because with ls I get this response

```
C:\wamp\www\site17>git ls-remote virt55973@www.vivule.ee:~/domeenid/www.vivule.e
e/kraater/.git
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/yod/.ssh/id_rsa':
efe835684e95fe092bb7bfdc561cb0a16ad3fd00        HEAD
00b183227efac6a25531499a2c172cba6b52a320        refs/heads/checkout
00b183227efac6a25531499a2c172cba6b52a320        refs/heads/master
efe835684e95fe092bb7bfdc561cb0a16ad3fd00        refs/heads/set_up_angular2
```

I think the problem is with SSH acting differently with commits, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I think I can put my finger on it, but I won't post this as an answer because it got downvoted last time I did.  I have see this error in Bitbucket when my local certificate did not match what I entered into the Bitbucket config page.  Somewhere did you tell the Git server what your local cert is?  Please check to make sure you have done this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you mean ssl cert? Just to test this theory I set [http] sslVerify = false in my local and remote repository. No avail. Do you mean some other certification method?

Comment: When using Bitbucket (and I'm assuming Github as well), you need to paste your local SSL cert into a form on the provider's website.  This tells the provider that it should recognize your cert when you present it.  I had your error message when using Bitbucket, and this was the problem.  Sorry if it doesn't help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in my webserver it seems to be done with SSH (which I have pasted to the host provider form). Would I be able to even use ls-remote if the key was false?

Comment: You have me beat unfortunately, but I upvoted you so you will keep getting noticed by others.